# g++4.4: iostream move semantics

Tags: c++, iostream, move-semantics

I was trying to create a move constructor for a class that aggregates an `ostringstream`.  However, I keep running into

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4.5/bits/ios_base.h:790: error: 
  ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
```

This is the simplest code I could come up with

```
struct C {
    C(){ s << "start! "; }
    C(C&& c): s( std::move(c.s) ){ s << " moved "; }
    std::ostringstream s;
private:
    C(const C&);
};

C f() { return C(); }

int main(){
    C c=f();
    c.s << "aha";
    std::cout << c.s.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Is the iostreams library intended to implement move semantics?  Or is it merely g++4.4.5 that doesn't support them yet?

Comment: Move semantics are only supposed to be an optimization for copy. If non copyable classes could be moved it would create confusion like the old unique_ptr. Use smart pointers if you need to play with streams

Comment: Dani, that's not true, there are plenty of non-copyable types that are movable where it isn't just an optimisation, e.g. `std::unique_lock`, `std::unique_ptr` (the "old unique_ptr" you refer to is `std::auto_ptr` which is confusing, but it predates move semantics), and as in the question, `std::ostringstream`. Iostreams will be movable in the GCC 5.0 release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iostreams are movable, but only if you have C++11 support. Gcc 4.4 is probably not enough for that.

The private base class copy constructor is there exactly to make the classes non-copyable (but possibly movable).